# prepopulate field values while creating a new record using lightning flow

Tags: lightning, visual-flows, automated-process

I have created a flow with 3 screens and placed on the opportunity record page using lightning app builder.

I need to create case record from a flow. So I want to pre-populate some values for the new case record with values coming from the opportunity. In the end, I want the case to be created under that specific opportunity so need to update the Opportunity lookup field on Case with the opty ID I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have the Opportunity Id as a variable, after the user fills out the form and hits next, in your 'Create Record' action just add a row and set

`Case.Opportunity__c` (the lookup field) = `opportunityId` (the variable).

[image: FlowBuilderCreateRecord]

You can also use the 'Get Record' action to query for the Opportunity record (and  any field whose value you want) and store it in a 'record variable'. You can then use the same approach as above to set any field on the case to the value `{!Opportunity.[Field]}`

Comment: Can you please help me out how should I have the Opportunity Id as a variable?

Comment: Where are you using the flow? 
Create an 'input variable' and label it OpportunityId. Wherever you are using the screen flow (for example: on the Opportunity record page), you can pass it the opportunity Id)

See resources: 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000id3jQAA
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000eFX2QAM

Comment: I would do this trail to grasp a more complete knowledge of the resources available to you:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/flow-builder